# python selenium webscraping. Mistake in ```while``` loop. how to make the code wait for page to load and try again

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, wait

I am trying to scrape a table from a JavaScript website using selenium in python. The process is to submit a form using selenium driver through python and then retrieving the loaded page. As the website is slow, sometimes the table which is loaded for the previous selection remains in the page and the code scrapes the wrong data instead of waiting for the new table to load. I want to ensure that the table I scrape corresponds with the selection I made from the dropdown. As the page may take anywhere between 5 seconds to several minutes to load, specifying waiting time may not work. So I put a second `while` loop within the first `while` loop to verify that the names in the dropdown and the resulting table are same before scraping the data. But it seems not to be working and the data is being scraped without verifying the names first. I am giving a sample below. Please tell me how to get it correct.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import time
from selenium import webdriver 
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from retry import retry

# Web page url 
driver.get("http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/dynamic_work_details.aspx?page=S&lflag=eng&state_name=KERALA&state_code=16&fin_year=2020-2021&source=national&Digest=s5wXOIOkT98cNVkcwF6NQA") 
x=0
while True:
    try:
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)  
        # Find District of option 
        x = driver.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_dist') 
        drop = Select(x) 

        # Select by value 
        drop.select_by_value("1613")

        time.sleep(6) 

        # Find Block of option 
        x = driver.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_blk') 
        drop = Select(x) 

        # Select by value 
        drop.select_by_value("1613001")

        time.sleep(4) 

        # Find GP of option 
        x = driver.find_element_by_id('ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_pan') 
        drop = Select(x) 

        # Select by value 
        drop.select_by_value("1613001001")

        time.sleep(4) 


        search_button = driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1")
        search_button.click()
        time.sleep(8)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        tables = soup.find_all('table')
        dfs = pd.read_html(str(tables))
        
        #print(dfs[4])
        
        df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(dfs[4].to_csv(index=False)), skiprows=1, header=[0,1])
        c = df1.iat[1,3]
        print(c)
       
        c == "Alayamon"
        while True:
            try:
                df1.to_csv("break.csv", index=False)
                break
            except:
                if x:
                    print("waiting...")
                    x = False
            
        
        driver.close()
        break
    except:
        if x:
            print("Error")
            x = False
```

Comment: How would anyone willing to help you know which dropdowns you selected to populate the data?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying that. There is a name corresponding to each drop.select_by_value. It can be seen if we check the inspect element. The name of the third drop.select_by_value will be same as the value in the third row of the scraped table. I specified that name as the verifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi hope this helps just slot it in before your webpage loads

```
driver = chromedriver()
driver.get("http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/dynamic_work_details.aspx?page=S&lflag=eng&state_name=KERALA&state_code=16&fin_year=2020-2021&source=national&Digest=s5wXOIOkT98cNVkcwF6NQA")
timeout = 3
try:
   element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'main'))
   WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
       print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
finally:
       print("Page loaded")
```

Documentation found on https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-wait-for-page-to-load/